# Android rotation animation with ScrollView

Tags: android, animation, scrollview

I am trying to animate a custom scroll view which I have resized its using `LayoutParams` (height & width).

Something like that:

```
ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", rotationValue);
rotation.start();
```

Animation runs fine but all of the ScrollView's content is drawn within the rotation pivot bounds. Images attached.

Anyone?
Thanks.

before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIxZL.png

after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWtag.png

Comment: Have you got the solution? If yes then please post it in answer. I have required.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you need to set the `android:clipChildren` attribute on the parent `ViewGroup`.

Quoting the [`ViewGroup` documentation for `android:clipChildren`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3aclipChildren):

> Defines whether a child is limited to draw inside of its bounds or not. This is useful with animations that scale the size of the children to more than 100% for instance. In such a case, this property should be set to false to allow the children to draw outside of their bounds. The default value of this property is true.

So either add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the XML layout, or call the ViewGroup's [setClipChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setClipChildren%28boolean%29) method if you are building the interface programatically.

Comment: Sorry. already tried all possible clipChildren variations. Still no go. What ever content is in the scroll view is always drawn out of bounds on rotation.